# How to Show Standard Post and Custom Post in Same Section at Homepage?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, 404-error, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to show both my standard posts and custom posts on my homepage. I've got the following code working, but it's causing a 404 error if I assign a **custom homepage**. If I keep the setting of "Your homepage displays" as "Your latest posts" the problem is fixed.

How can I solve the 404 error when I assign a custom homepage?

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'add_my_custom_post_type');

/**
 * @param WP_Query $query
 * @return WP_Query
 */
function add_my_custom_post_type($query) {
    if(
        empty($query->query['post_type'])
        or $query->query['post_type'] === 'post'
        and !is_admin()
    ){
        $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'news'));
    }
}
```

I tried asking it from chatgpt but it didn't worked